# Android app links not working with Chrome Custom Tabs

Tags: android, kotlin, applinks, chrome-custom-tabs

I have application which use app links for login in the browser outside of the app and is redirected back after login is completed.
This works fine with android native browsers but fails when I'm using Chrome Custom Tabs. User is logged in custom tabs and not redirected back to the app, so I wonder if is it possible to 
use app links with custom tabs in the same way as with the native browsers?

manifest configuration

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

<data
    android:host="my-host"
    android:scheme="https" />
```

working implementation in native browsers

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
ContextCompat.startActivity(context, intent, null)
```

failing redirect using chrome custom tabs

```
val customTabsIntent = CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
    .build()

customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context, Uri.parse(url))
```

Comment: I've got the exact same issue. You can try to define a fix path after your host uri, it may work : https://my-host/redirect.

Comment: What's the dependency version you are using for chrome custom tabs?
com.android.support:customtabs

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Because your deeplink url is like that of a website, the Chrome Custom Tab will always try to load it as a webpage instead of redirecting. What you could do is use a scheme not commonly supported by a browser like `app-name://` then your host could be `redirect-to` so what this would play out to be would be

```
 <data
  android:host="redirect-to"
  android:scheme="app-name" />
```

This way only your app, will be the one to resolve this url. But take note when you use this type of url, it may not appear as a link in some apps like e-mails.

Comment: Thanks for reply but this won't work in my scenario. What I currently do is:
1. Open login url from webview in chrome browser
2. After login is completed I'm redirected back to my single webview host from 3rd party provider with auth token - which always redirects to "https://my-host/auth-token" after I changed the https scheme it will be never opened in my native app.

And this works as expected, just doesn't work when I replace chrome browser to custom tabs

Comment: this is great hint, I was struggling with this. changed my scheme to app-id (com.company.appname). updated redirect url in keycloak also. and it worked.

Comment: i changed mine from https to something else and it worked